# Version compatibility between watchOS and iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos

I assume that an Apple Watch running a particular version of watchOS can't be paired with an iPhone running any iOS version, right?

Is there a table that list the compatibility between the different versions of watchOS and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

There are latest `watchOS 5`, and `watchOS 6 beta` version.

As per Apple official documentation:

> watchOS 5 requires iPhone 5s or later with iOS 12 or later, and one of
> the following Apple Watch models:
>
> Apple Watch Series 1
>
> Apple Watch Series 2
>
> Apple Watch Series 3
>
> Apple Watch Series 4

Reference:- [Watch OS 5](https://www.apple.com/in/watchos/watchos-5/)

Also, There are list of 'watchOS' version which are 'iOS' version based.

See this: [Watch OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WatchOS)

Comment: My assumption have been that a particular watchOS version is only compatible with the iOS version on which it is based. For exemple, that watchOS 5 is only compatible with iOS 12. However, requirement for watchOS 5 is iOS 12 or later in your example. Thus, watchOS 5 should be compatible with iOS 13. What about watchOS 2 that required iOS 9 or later. is it compatible with iOS 12? There must be a compatibility list somewhere.